# What is the meaning of a measure $\mu$ being stationary, i.e. $P_\mu^t(A)=\int_{\mathbb R}p^t(x,B)\mu(dx)=\mu(A)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

We say that $\mu$ is stationary if for all $t>0$, $$P_\mu^t(A):=\int_{\mathbb R}p^t(x,B)\mu(dx)=\mu(A),\tag{*}$$
where $(p^t)$ is a transition probability kernel, i.e. $x\mapsto p(x,B)$ is measurable for all $B$ measurable, $B\mapsto p(x,B)$ is a probability measure for all $x$ and $p^t$ satisfy Kolmogorov-Chapman equation i.e. $$p_{t+s}(x,A)=\int_{\mathbb R}p_s(x, dy)p_t(y,B).$$

Can someone explain me what $(*)$ means ? My interpretation would be :

$P_t^\mu(A)=\int_{\mathbb R}p^t(x,A)\mu(dx)$ represent the probability that the process reach $A$ at time $t$ whenever $X_0$ follow the law $\mu$. Now, $\mu(A)$ is the probability that the process start in $A$.

So, my interpretation would be that $\mu$ is stationary if for all $t$, to reach $A$ in time $t$ for all $t$, is the same than to start in $A$.

The problem with this interpretation, it's I don't really understand how a process can reach $A$ in time $t$ for all $t$ unless $X$ stay in $A$ for all $s\leq t$...

Comment: A distribution is stationary if it doesn't change in time. This doesn't mean that there is no probability current out of a set $A$, only that if there is then it is compensated exactly by an inward current. Think of the Markov chain with transition probability matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$ for some intuition.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you. But referring to the formula I gave, I'm not so sure to see what it means the fact that it doesn't change in time.

Comment: The idea is just that $P^t_\mu$ is the distribution of $X_t$ when $X_0$ is distributed as $\mu$. So now what happens is sometimes $X_0$ is in $A$ and $X_t$ is not, but the probability of that is exactly equal to the probability that $X_0$ is not in $A$ and $X_t$ is.

Comment: @Ian: Sorry, I don't really understand your last sentence. So, as I interpret it is, $P_\mu^t(A)$ is the probability that $X_t$ in $A$ whenever $X_0\sim \mu$. Now, if $\mu$ is stationary, then for all $t$, $X_t\sim X_0\sim \mu$. In other word, it doesn't depend on $t$. Right ?

Comment: The distribution doesn't depend on $t$. But your confusion in the question suggests that you think that this means that $X_t$ for a fixed trajectory doesn't depend on $t$, which does not have to be the case. If you think of the example in my first comment, if you start from a uniform distribution, it is stationary, but there is still a transition going on at every time step. If you've taken chemistry, this is exactly the "dynamic equilibrium" concept that is discussed in that setting.